# Save the session directly to database bypassing the session store?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, session, express-session

I'm using SQL Server as database and I couldn't get the session store npm package listed for SQL Server to work. Are there any concerns with inserting the sessionID into the database directly and then verifying what the client sends as sessionID matches the database sessionID? Do I need to tell it somehow to not save the session in memory?

```
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

app.use(session({
    genid: uuidv1,
    name: 'session',
    secret: 'thesecretcode',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false, /*no https*/
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true,
        maxAge: 600
    }
}));

app.all('*', requireAuthentication);
function requireAuthentication(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.sessionID);


    if (req.session.user) {
        req.session.views++;
        console.log(req.session.user)
        res.render('home'); /*when logged in*/

    } else {
        req.session.views = 1;
        req.session.user = 'MrUser';
        next();

    }
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const saltRounds = 10;
    bcrypt.hash(req.sessionID, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
        let promise = insert(req.session.user, hash);

    });

    res.render('landing'); /*when not logged in*/
})

function insert(theuser, sessionID) {
    var thequery = "insert into session (sessiondata,sessionid,lasttouchedutc) values(@theuser,@sessionID,getdate())";
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var con = new msSqlConnecter.msSqlConnecter(config);
        con.connect().then(function() {
            new con.Request(thequery)
                .addParam("theuser", TYPES.VarChar, theuser)
                .addParam("sessionID", TYPES.VarChar, sessionID)
                .onComplate(function(count, datas) {
                    resolve(datas);
                    // res.end()
                }).onError(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }).Run();
        }).catch(function(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more performant to use Redis but what you're doing is fine.  Sessions have always been managed by matching a server-side cookie value to what is typically stored in an RDBMS.

Summary:

1. What you're doing is fine.
2. Use Redis to management sessions as it is much faster than hitting SQL server or any database